# List bullet points not centered vertically

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Please take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HukTW/11/) that contains an unordered list:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1
    <li>Item 2
```

I use Twitter Bootstrap, and the first button under "Step 1" is over two lines. Notice the bullet point does not align in the center vertically.

How can I fix this?

Comment: A JSFiddle is great, but please also add some relevant code  here. With only an external link, the question will have no value to future readers if JSFiddle ever  goes down. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use

```
li a {  vertical-align:middle; }
```

[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/HukTW/14/)